# How to compare two arrays in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to compare two arrays and if they are equal, add a new attribute to html.

First my html

```
<ul class="checkout__delivery-collect-shoplist" data-bind="foreach: currentOptions ">
  <li class="checkout__delivery-collect-shop js-delivery-item active">
    <h6><em data-bind="text: label">Name1</em></h6>
  </li>
  <li class="checkout__delivery-collect-shop js-delivery-item">
    <h6><em data-bind="text: label">Name2</em></h6>
  </li>
</ul>
```

First I am creating new array with text

```
var arr = [];
jQuery('em[data-bind="text: label"]').each(function() {
    arr.push(jQuery(this).text().split(';'));
});
```

Also, I have another array with text

```
var Managerss = Manager.GlobalData[2].options
Managerss.filter(x => x.payment_checkmo === '1').map(x => x.label);
```

It will give

```
["Name1", "Name2"]
0: "Name1"
1: "Name2"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

So I first need to compare these arrays and if this true create new attribute `data-payment = '0'` to `li.class checkout__delivery-collect-shop js-delivery-item`

Example what I want

```
<ul class="checkout__delivery-collect-shoplist" data-bind="foreach: currentOptions ">
  <li class="checkout__delivery-collect-shop js-delivery-item active" data-payment='0'>
    <h6><em data-bind="text: label">Name1</em></h6>
  </li>
  <li class="checkout__delivery-collect-shop js-delivery-item" data-payment='0'>
    <h6><em data-bind="text: label">Name2</em></h6>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This looks like knockout.js. Why are you using jquery instead of using the `currentOptions` array of view model for DOM maipulation?

Comment: What do you mean by compare, do the position of the elements also need to match, do you only want co compare length.. please elaborate

Comment: Could your reformulate ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vitzkrieg/SdkRZ/

Comment: @Smail Galijasevic i mean i have two arrays i need to compare them and if they compared add new attribute to li.class

Comment: @Johncarbon are arrays same if they have same elements but different order?

Comment: @Smail Galijasevic order does not matter arrays always same. How to create new attr if they always same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compares each element inside the 2 arrays, you can edit this code to do whatever you want to do.

```js
function Compare() 
{ 
 var a = ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3']; 
 var b = ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3']; 
  // if length is not equal 
  if(a.length!=b.length) 
   return "False"; 
  else
  { 
  // comapring each element of array 
   for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) 
   if(a[i]!=b[i]) 
    return "False"; 
    return "True"; 
  } 
} 
var v = Compare(); 
document.write(v);
```